# Is it safe to remove .pdb directory from a symbol storage if I don't use them anymore?

Tags: windows, visual-c++, debug-symbols, symbol-server, symstore

My local symbol storage directory contains plenty of files which I'd like to erase (because I think they are unused) or move to a separate directory. I'm know that [AgeStore](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff538002%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [SymStore](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681417%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) can be used to trim a symbol storage - but neither seems to support the use case of removing information for specific files from the symbol storage.

My local symbol storage looks something like

```
D:\Symbols\
  +-> 000Admin\
  +-> myownlibrary.pdb\
  |     +->123456789\
  |     +->abcdef\
  +-> vc60.pdb\
  |     +->123456789\
  |     +->abcdef\
  ...
  +-> ws2_32.pdb\
  |     +->123456789\
  |     +->abcdef\
  ...
```

Is it safe to just remove directories like `vc60.pdb` and everything beneath that altogether, or would that break fetching symbols/binaries from the symbol storage?

Comment: Define 'safe'. If you delete one PDB, you just lose those symbols.

Comment: @david.pfx 'safe' as in: deleting one `.pdb` subdirectory will not influence using invocations of, say, `symstore del` to remove everything which was added in a certain transaction.